# flickering twin images in memory game

Tags: image, dart

I have a problem of flickering twin images in https://github.com/dzenanr/educ_memory_game.

In the Board class of view/board.dart, the following code in the _imageBox method creates and loads images:

```
  var imagePath = 'images/${cell.image}';
  ImageElement image = new Element.tag('img');
  image.src = imagePath;
  image.onLoad.listen((event) {
    context.drawImageToRect(image, new Rect(x, y, boxSize, boxSize));
  });
```

A click on a board cell shows an image for a second. When the same 2 images are discovered, those twin images stay displayed , but they flicker every second (a timer refresh interval).

In order to solve the flickering problem, I create those images in a constructor of the Board class:

```
for (var cell in memory.cells) {
  ImageElement image = new Element.tag('img');
  image.src = 'images/${cell.image}';
  imageMap[cell.image] = image;
}
```

Then, I get an image from the map. However neither of the following two works:

```
  ImageElement image = imageMap[cell.image];
  image.onLoad.listen((event) {
    context.drawImageToRect(image, new Rect(x, y, boxSize, boxSize)); 
  });
```

or

```
  ImageElement image = imageMap[cell.image];
  context.drawImageToRect(image, new Rect(x, y, boxSize, boxSize));
```

Answer (score 2):

- Changing the src attribute of the image imply a network access and is not good, you have to used the cached images.
- To display the image correctly, just change the _imageBox function a little bit.

  ```
   void _imageBox(Cell cell) {
    var x = cell.column * boxSize;
    var y = cell.row * boxSize;
    context.beginPath();
    // Moved at the beginning otherwise it is drawn above the image.
    context.rect(x, y, boxSize, boxSize);
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
    if (cell.hidden ) {
      context.fillStyle = HIDDEN_CELL_COLOR_CODE;
      var centerX = cell.column * boxSize + boxSize / 2;
      var centerY = cell.row * boxSize + boxSize / 2;
      var radius = 4;
      context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * PI, false);
    } else {
      ImageElement image = imageMap[cell.image]; // if decomment, comment the above 3 lines
      context.drawImageToRect(image, new Rect(x, y, boxSize, boxSize));
    }
   }
  ```